# Transform mongodb array document to a single field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have such document structure:

```
{
  favourite_shops: [
    {
      shop_id: "5961352278cba91cc6a6e8cc",
      time: "2017-07-11T14:43:35.465Z"
    },
    {
      shop_id: "5964e446c15c760f9b646d99",
      time: "2017-07-11T14:44:40.429Z"
    },
    {
      shop_id: "5964e446c15c760f9b646d98",
      time: "2017-07-11T14:44:50.988Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I transform this to something like this:

```
{
  favourite_shops: [
    "5961352278cba91cc6a6e8cc",
    "5964e446c15c760f9b646d99",
    "5964e446c15c760f9b646d98" 
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Veeram no its not working, it is not doing any tranformation.

Comment: do you want the result as query response or trying to modify after you get the response.

Comment: Sorry I meant `db.collectonname.aggregate({$project:{"favourite_shops":"$favourite_shops.shop_id"}});`

Comment: @pe got thrayagupd I want it as query response and I have  resolved my problem

Comment: @Veeram {$project:{"favourite_shops":"$fa‌​vourite_shops.shop_i‌​d"} only shows product id of fiest sub array . It does not show ids of all array elemenst.

Comment: what is your mongodb server version ?

Comment: @Veeram its v3.4.5

Comment: okay may be you are trying to ask separate question. It works as expected for the document that you've posted in question. Please create a new question if thats the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) on the array itself and get only the fields you need. (This is done within the query itself not after you receive the documents)

example.

given documents;

```
> db.Shopping.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59651ce38828356e1a39fde9"),
    "favourite_shops" : [
        {
            "shop_id" : "5961352278cba91cc6a6e8cc",
            "time" : "2017-07-11T14:43:35.465Z"
        },
        {
            "shop_id" : "5964e446c15c760f9b646d99",
            "time" : "2017-07-11T14:44:40.429Z"
        },
        {
            "shop_id" : "5964e446c15c760f9b646d98",
            "time" : "2017-07-11T14:44:50.988Z"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59665cf3d8145b41e5d2f5da"),
    "favourite_shops" : [
        {
            "shop_id" : "2222",
            "time" : "2017-07-11T14:43:35.465Z"
        },
        {
            "shop_id" : "4444",
            "time" : "2017-07-11T14:44:40.429Z"
        },
        {
            "shop_id" : "6666",
            "time" : "2017-07-11T14:44:50.988Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

`$map` on `favourite_shops` array (`{$match}` block is optional, you can remove if you want shopping id for all documents)

```
> db.Shopping.aggregate([[
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": ObjectId("59651ce38828356e1a39fde9")
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "my_favourite_shops": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$favourite_shops",
          "as": "each_shop",
          "in": "$$each_shop.shop_id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59651ce38828356e1a39fde9"),
    "my_favourite_shops" : [
        "5961352278cba91cc6a6e8cc",
        "5964e446c15c760f9b646d99",
        "5964e446c15c760f9b646d98"
    ]
}
```

And, with mongodb 3.4.4, I simply could `$project` on nested field,

```
db.Shopping.aggregate([{"$project": {"my_favourite_shops": "$favourite_shops.shop_id"}}]).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59651ce38828356e1a39fde9"),
    "my_favourite_shops" : [
        "5961352278cba91cc6a6e8cc",
        "5964e446c15c760f9b646d99",
        "5964e446c15c760f9b646d98"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59665cf3d8145b41e5d2f5da"),
    "my_favourite_shops" : [
        "2222",
        "4444",
        "6666"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You don't need `$map` for this in anything above MongoDB 3.0. Simply `{ "$project": "$my_favourite_shops.shop_id" }` does the same thing, and is essentially a shortcut for `$map` with a single property.

Comment: @NeilLunn {$project:{"favourite_shops":"$fa‌​vourite_shops.shop_i‌​d"} only shows one product id. But I need to get all product ids of all array element.

Comment: thanks @NeilLunn. `$project` on nested field works properly in mongo 3.4.4. I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have such data structure:

```
const data = {
  favourite_shops: [
    {
      shop_id: "5961352278cba91cc6a6e8cc",
      time: "2017-07-11T14:43:35.465Z"
    },
    {
      shop_id: "5964e446c15c760f9b646d99",
      time: "2017-07-11T14:44:40.429Z"
    },
    {
      shop_id: "5964e446c15c760f9b646d98",
      time: "2017-07-11T14:44:50.988Z"
    }
  ]
};
```

Just a bit of **ES6 magic**:

```
const result = {
  favourite_shops: []
};

data.favourite_shops.forEach(el => result.favourite_shops.push(el.shop_id));
```

Second elegant approach:

```
const result = {
  favourite_shops: data.favourite_shops.map(el => el.shop_id)
};
```